# How to store a checkbox value to keep the checkbox actualized on tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Using a mode menu with tampermonkey, some functions are already loaded while the checkbox is still off.

I was wondering how to keep the checkbox value after reload with tampermonkey ? Else it mays disturb the user. I searched everywhere but it doesn't work with tampermonkey.

In this following case , I wish to get the value of #Checkbox (6th line of the code)

Here is my mini-code :

```
var zNode       = document.createElement ('div');
zNode.innerHTML = '<span class="sg-button__icon"><div id="parameters" class="sg-icon sg-icon--adaptive sg-icon--x24"><svg  class="sg-icon__svg"><use xlink:href="#icon-settings"></use></svg></div></span><button class="sg-button sg-button--solid-mint" id="myButton" type="button">'
                + 'Check Point Transfering</button>'
                + '   <label class="switch"><input id="Checkbox" type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label>'
                + '<p id="darkmodetext">Dark Mode</p>'
                ;
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'myContainer');
zNode.setAttribute ('class', 'sg-box sg-box--no-border sg-box brn-white-background-box-light-gray');
zNode.setAttribute ('class', 'vertical-center');
document.body.appendChild (zNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

GM_setValue and GM_getValue should work

```
// @grant    GM.getValue
// @grant    GM.setValue
```

They will allow values to be stored across page loads.

```
GM_setValue('checkbox', 'checked');
```

To retrieve the value

```
let myVar = GM_getValue('checkbox');
```

Then if the variable has the value you are looking for

```
if(myVar === 'checked'){
  // do stuff
}else{
  // do different stuff
}
```